# Creating a perl script to batch process files

Tags: perl, loops, batch-file, logic

I have this line of code:

```
convert 1234_Page_1_....png 1234_Page_2_....png output.pdf
```

This merges those particular pngs to a single pdf (using ImageMagick). I have a bunch of files in this format. I would like to perform this merging/converting-to-pdf action on files that have the same number before the "*Page*". Sometimes there are more than two pages to convert.

I would like to have this done in a perl script that I can run on Windows.

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to call convert(1) as few times as necessary:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %processed = ();
for my $prefix (map { /^(\d+)/ } glob('[1-9]*_Page_*.png')) {
    next if $processed{$prefix}++;
    system("convert ${prefix}_Page_*.png ${prefix}_output.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) (maybe [mingw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw) too?) installed, try this:

```
for i in `seq 1234 1350` ; do convert ${i}_Page_*.png ${i}_output.pdf ; done
```

Comment: Thanks, but if there is a file missing from the sequence, will the script hang up?

Comment: Jake, no, but it will throw ugly error messages that might hide important failures.

Comment: I got this message: Missing $ on loop variable at script.pl line 1.

Comment: That's a bash-script, it won't work from perl. If you don't already have cygwin or mingw installed, it probably isn't worth the hassle. But if you do have them installed (and a lot of programmers do :) then it's an easy tool for some of these operations.

Comment: I got cygwin installed, but when I try running the script, i get the error: 
line:1 syntax error near unexpected token '$'\r''
line:1 'for i in 'seq 312800 312860' ;

Comment: This is not a complete Bash script. You could either run this from the command-line or put it in a script with an appropriate [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use an asterisk for this? I will try it right now.

```
convert 1234_Page_*.png output.pdf
```

---

If you want the readable file, here you go:

```
import os

for i in xrange(int(raw_input('How many sets of pages are there? '))):
  os.system('convert {0}_Page_*.png output_{0}.pdf'.format(str(i)))
```

Here's a one-liner:

```
python -c "import os; [os.system('convert {0}_Page_*.png output_{0}.pdf'.format(str(i))) for i in xrange(int(raw_input('How many sets of pages are there? ')))]"
```

Comment: I believe so, but I'm looking for help looping through all of the files that I have. I.e. 1234, 1235, 1236 etc. I have thousands of such files.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Would you mind a Python script? I can make a single command to run for this really easily.

Comment: Mine isn't much different than your's. Mine just asks you how many pages there are, and if you type in a big number, it goes into a death-count which locks up the console window until it finishes ;)

Comment: Perhaps not that different, but Python is probably more ubiquitous than cygwin or mingw. :)

Comment: I actually am writing a Python shell, just because I can't figure out how to use Bash ;) It's called Pysh. Creative, huh?

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried installing cygwin a while back, but not sure it worked correctly. I'm installing Python right now to try the other code.

Comment: @Blender, awesome :) I'm afraid the finer points of sh scripting elude me, but I can monkey-see-monkey-do pretty well with it. :)

Comment: It's all Python. I can't script shell to save my life (well, I can do `nano` and `cat` and `grep`, but that's about it)...