# Creating a PHP script from BASH code to run on Windows

Tags: php, bash, for-loop

I have this line of code:

```
convert 1234_Page_1_....png 1234_Page_2_....png output.pdf
```

This merges the listed pngs to a single pdf (using ImageMagick). I have a bunch of PNG files in this format.  I would like to create a loop in PHP to run through the convert/merge action on all the files that I have. For all the files that have the same number before the "*Page*", I would like them to be merged to one PDF with that same number as a name. Sometimes there are more than two pages to convert.

For this example, I would like "1234_Page_1_....png" and "1234_Page_2_....png" to result as 1234.pdf. And I would like files "1235_Page_1_....png" and "1235_Page_2_....png" to result as 1235.pdf, and so on.

Here's what I've been told is the BASH way to handle the problem:

```
for i in `seq 1234 1350` ; do convert ${i}_Page_*.png ${i}_output.pdf ; done
```

I would like to have this done in a PHP script that I can run on Windows.

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Comment: Why not run [Bash on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/913912/78845)?

Comment: Also what was wrong with the Perl and Python scripts that you got in answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5347553/78845)?

Comment: Johnsyweb: I was unable to get your Python script to work. 
python -c "import os; [os.system('convert {0}_Page_*.png output_{0}.pdf'.format(str(i))) for i in xrange(int(raw_input('How many sets of pages are there? ')))]"
is what you suggested. Do I save this as a .py file and then do I need to install extra software? Also, there is something not exactly right with the BASH script as I have cygwin installed and tried the above and got the error: line:1 syntax error near unexpected token '$'\r'' line:1 'for i in 'seq 312800 312860' ;

Comment: @Jake: This was not my script. Comments on those answers should be under those answers -- not on this page.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error message is that you edited the script using a Windows editor and then tried to run it in a Unix-type environment. Run `dos2unix scriptname` and the Windows line endings will be converted to Unix line endings. No more `$'\r'` errors. Also, in Bash use `for i in {1234..1350}` - there's no need to use `seq`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Ok, well you asked about it here. Sorry for mistaking you for the poster of the code. I'm pretty new with this stuff, so it's tough to have any success without thorough instructions. I was told that PHP would be the easiest way to execute scripts of this sort on Windows without the need for extra installs.

Comment: So... do you actually need a PHP script, like you've asked for (you'll need to PHP installed on your windows box)? Or do you need to fix up the Bash / Perl / Python script that you already have? Note that [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), so programming expertise is assumed in most answers. If you're looking for step-by-step installation instructions, this is probably the wrong forum.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Thanks for your encouragement. I wasn't sure if it was the script or the environment that was my problem, so when I wasn't able to execute the code help that was given before, I defaulted to asking for a language that I've executed before. The BASH line of code works in the cygwin environment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error message is that you edited the script using a Windows editor and then tried to run it in a Unix-type environment. Run `dos2unix scriptname` and the Windows line endings will be converted to Unix line endings. No more `$'\r'` errors. Also, in Bash use `for i in {1234..1350}` - there's no need to use `seq`.